# Swift add constraint extension to Protocol that has an associated type

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

When I add a constraint extension to a protocol that has an associated type, the swift compiler ignores my constraint.

When I write:

```swift
protocol Arr {
    associatedtype Element

    func node(_ at: Int) -> Element?
}

extension Arr where Element == String {
    func node(_ at: Int) -> String? {
        nil
    }
}

struct Doo: Arr {
}
```

Xcode builds successfully and it thinks my `Doo`'s `Element` is `String`. It ignores the `where Element == String` constraint.

When I write:

```swift
protocol Arr {
    associatedtype Element

    func node(_ at: Int) -> Element?
}

extension Arr where Element == String {
    func node(_ at: Int) -> Element? { // use Element
        nil
    }
}

struct Doo: Arr {
}
```

Xcode shows an error, as expected.

Is this an Xcode bug or a Swift feature?

Xcode version: `Version 13.1 (13A1030d)`

Swift version:

```
swift-driver version: 1.26.9 Apple Swift version 5.5.1 (swiftlang-1300.0.31.4 clang-1300.0.29.6)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx12.0
```

Comment: I think this is because the constraints are applied much later (I don't have any sources for this though). `Doo` got the `node` method "as soon as" you say `: Arr`. And then it sees that `node` returns `String?`, so it infers that `Element` must be `String`. If `node` returned `Element?`, the inference would not have been possible. Are you aware that Swift infers associated types from method signatures?

Comment: The constraints are only checked when you attempt to invoke `node`. It's only then that the compiler will say "`node` is only available when ..."

Comment: `The Xcode show an error for me expected` - what's the error that you expect?

Comment: @Cristik Xcode show: `Type 'Doo' does not conform to protocol 'Arr'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that Swift will gladly satisfy protocol requirements, if it can extract them from the context.

For example, assuming the extension would not exist, and the `Doo` definition would be like this:

```swift
struct Doo: Arr {
    func node(_ at: Int) -> String? {
        nil
    }
}
```

, the the Swift compiler will happily fill the `Element` associated type.

A similar thing happens with your first snippet of code, `Doo` conforms to `Arr`, and the compiler finds a definition that satisfies all protocol requirements. Swift doesn't ignore the `Element == String` constraint, because it associates it with the `Doo` struct.

If you would add a second extension in a similar fashion, but for another type (an `Int` for example), you'll see that you receive the expected error. This happens because the compiler can no longer infer the protocol requirements.

The Swift compiler eagerly infers as much as possible from the context it can reach to, most of the time gives great results, sometimes not so great (especially when working with closures), and sometimes it gives unexpected results (like this one).

If you want to be sure that the compiler infers the types you want, a solution would be to explicitly declare all involved types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand you. The compiler apply function that in extension and then check constraint, and all fulfilled. It makes sense.

But this behavior is very strange, I will try to report a bug to swift project. 

I think compiler may check constraint that follow extension firstly and if it passed then add the functions or variable to `Doo` struct. 

Maybe this can reduce error that added by unexpectedly. Because in my first code snippet, the `Arr` protocol has a default `Element` value is `String`. This is unexpected. And it is hard to find that reason.

Comment: Sure, you can try filing a bug report, if you think this is incorrect behaviour, @sunny. Basically is the eagerness of the compiler that causes this, being overly helpful seems not to be the best sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

The errors in second case arises because Xcode is not able to infer the type of Element. If you specify it, everything compiles.

```
struct Doo: Arr {
    typealias Element = String
    
}
```

Comment: The question is not about why the error occurs, or how to fix it. It's the other way around, about why there is no error in the first code snippet.

Comment: In first case compiler is able to infer the type of `Element` because func `node` is said to return `String`.